# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!'

Tags: php

This is my `php` code

```
<?php   
    if ($_POST['submit']){
        if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="</br>Please enter your email address";
        else if !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error = "</br>Please enter a valid email address.";

     if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="</br>Please enter a password.";

   if($error) echo "There were error(s)".$error;
  }
?>
```

I don't find any mistake there. But it is showing this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting '(' in
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\abc\projects\s_diary.php on line 5

I am not much experienced in php. So, please help me...

Comment: check this line : `if !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ` put `!` inside bracket. First write the code properly using identations ..

Comment: @Maruf please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Comment: people are not interested in marking answer as accepted. Wastage of time and effort. deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first `else if` is missing parentheses around its if-expression, as in:

```
else if ( !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ) ...
        ^                                                       ^
        |                                                       |
```